# Memory error with embedding python in C application

Tags: python, linux, gcc, arm, beagleboard

I am trying to embed a python interpreter into my C program for my ARM system (beagleboard). My test program is this for simplicity:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{ 
    Py_SetProgramName(argv[0]); 
    Py_Initialize(); 
    Py_Main(argc, argv); 
    Py_Finalize(); 
    return 0; 
}
```

When I try to "import math" or any other common module, I get this error:

*** Error in `python_test': double free or corruption (out): 0x429bd020 ***

I only get this error when I cross compile for the ARM (beagleboard) system. It works if I compile and run it on my Host PC, windows and ubuntu (x86).

Does anyone know what can be wrong? The GCC I used to cross compile is 4.7.2 and the python version is 2.7.3.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have those modules available on the ARM system?

Comment: Thanks for the help. With your comment I tried compiling with the shared libraries instead of the static libraries of python and it worked. Thanks a lot.